# How can I display all text in Cell of GridView

Tags: c#

I use GridView in my C# application, and the cell seems too small.
[image]

I find the prop of GridView, but I find nothing about it. How can I display all text in Cell?

Comment: Here is a similar question that has been answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287077/multiline-text-in-gridview-not-working?rq=1

Comment: It is asp, may application is not web

Answer (score 1):

Under `Columns` Collection property there is `AutoSizeMode` under `Layout`. And use for example `DisplayedCells` and see for yourself.

For `Word Wrap` you could set it programmatically like:

```
// Columns[1] for 2nd column based on your example.
dataGridView.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.true;
```

But don't set the `AutoSizeMode` as above or else the columns will still expand.

You could set it also manually under `Columns` Collection property and under `Appearance` select `Default Cell Style` and then set `WrapMode` to true.

Comment: Edper, this way can display all text, but I do not want to change width of cell. Can I display multiline text in gridview?