# How to break string at particular location to show it in grid-view?

Tags: asp.net

How should I break the string at particular location and put it at new line in grid-views column ? 
I tried :

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
 e.Row.Cells[4].Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word;"); 
}
```

But this is not helping.

Comment: please show .aspx code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287077/multiline-text-in-gridview-not-working